# How to create ZIPs with the content of every folder

Tags: windows, batch, compression, zip, 7-zip

I have several folders and I need to compress the content of each folder in a separate ZIP file. However, every ZIP should only contain the content of each folder and not the folder itself.

The following code creates a file with the folder included. It is close to what I'm looking for, but I'm not there yet.

```
for /d %%X in (*) do  "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.zip" "%%X\"
```

What I get: `XXX.zip > XXX(folder) > content`
What I want: `XXX.zip > content`

How can I do this?

Comment: If you open a command shell and type "7z /?" it will give you a list of command-line parameters.  I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "every zip compress only the content", do you mean that you want to have a separate zip file for each folder?

Comment: Yes, I wish to have a seperate zip for each folder. BUT I wish to only compress the content of each folder (having so a ZIP of only what is inside the folder) and not the folder itself. I'll edit the main post (pardon my english)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%~X.zip" "%%~X\*"
```

and if this doesn't work:

```
for /d %%X in (*) do  for %%Y in ("%%~X\*") do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%~X.zip" "%%~Y"
```

Comment: Thanks.

The first code don't work, do

 'XXX.zip>XXX(folder)>content'
.  
The second one creates the zip's of each folder but each zip is empty.

Comment: @Erues the first command works fine here, for the second I made a fix. Please check your paths and the version of `7zip`, current is `9.20`.